# Which Image Formats are Supported by CANVAS in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Like .jpg or .jpeg , which image formats are supported by Canvas in html5.?

I mean to say what kind of image formats direct display inside canvas on call **context.drawImage(image,dx,dy,dw.dh)**...

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: As the source of the image is an image-element (except for other canvas-elements) I'd say: every image that can be displayed by the target browser is available for canvas. (at least for [gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) this is the case)

Comment: but tif file is not displaying.. How can i check whether format is supported or not inside canvas >

Comment: put the source in an image-tag and have the browser render it. No image -> no support for canvas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The images supported will depend on your browser. You have no `tif` support? And you're using Chrome?

[Here is a list of image formats supported by browser.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)

You could either convert your image types, or try and find plugins to support more image types.